# Cannot bulk load because the file, BULK INSERT error code 3: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

When I am using this code:

```
select @CHEMIN_FICHIER = 'C:\\crm_tmp\\Images\\Equipements\\' + @NOM_FICHIER;
```

it works well.

But this code is vulnerable to SQL injection, so I changed it to this:

```
select @CHEMIN_FICHIER = 'C:\\rm_tmp\\Images\\Equipements\\' + REPLACE(REPLACE(QUOTENAME(@NOM_FICHIER) , '[', ''), ']', '');
```

Both result in the same path, when I use `SQL PRINT` statement.

But the second one is not working in bulk insert.

```
select @COMMANDE = 'INSERT INTO [image] (nom, donnees) SELECT ''' + @NOM_FICHIER + ''', BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk '''+ @CHEMIN_FICHIER + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB';
```

**PLAN B** to avoid SQL injection:

I also tried like this:

```
set @ParamDefinition = '@NOM_FICHIER nvarchar(255)'
select @CHEMIN_FICHIER = 'C:\\crm_tmp\\Images\\Equipements\\@NOM_FICHIER';
select @COMMANDE = 'INSERT INTO [image] (nom, donnees) SELECT ''' + @NOM_FICHIER + ''', BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk '''+ @CHEMIN_FICHIER + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB';
    
    execute sp_executesql @COMMANDE, @ParamDefinition, @NOM_FICHIER
```

but with plan B the value of `@NOM_FICHIER` is not evaluated so I got the path

```
C:\\crm_tmp\\Images\\Equipements\\@NOM_FICHIER
```

instead of

```
C:\\crm_tmp\\Images\\Equipements\\test.png
```

Answer (score 0):

After the  BULK command "'" instead of "'''"

```
DROP TABLE  if exists #image

CREATE  TABLE #image (nom NVARCHAR(255), donnees image)
 
DECLARE @NOM_FICHIER      NVARCHAR(255)  = N'Test.jpg'
DECLARE @CHEMIN_FICHIER   NVARCHAR(MAX)  = N'''C:\\crm_tmp\\Images\\Equipements\\'
DECLARE @COMMANDE         NVARCHAR(MAX)  = N'INSERT   #image   '                                                 + NCHAR(13)
                                         + N'       ( nom     '                                                  + NCHAR(13)
                                         + N'       , donnees '                                                  + NCHAR(13)
                                         + N'       )         '                                                  + NCHAR(13)
                                         + N'SELECT   ''' + @NOM_FICHIER + ''''                                  + NCHAR(13)
                                         + N'      ,  BulkColumn '                                               + NCHAR(13)
                                         + N'FROM     OPENROWSET ( Bulk '+ @CHEMIN_FICHIER + @NOM_FICHIER+ ''''  + NCHAR(13)
                                         + N'                    , SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB';
;
PRINT    @COMMANDE 
;   
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
        @statement    =  @COMMANDE
      , @params       =  N'@NOM_FICHIER nvarchar(255)'
      , @NOM_FICHIER  =  @NOM_FICHIER
;
SELECT  * 
FROM    #image
;
```